# Will all instances in a cluster placement group share the same operating system?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Will all instances in a cluster placement group share the same operating system?

Comment: Nothing of that sort in the documentation, I am able to create a placement group of varying operating systems with varying instance types without any trouble.Even though it is recommended to use same kind of instances. [Placement group rules and limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html#concepts-placement-groups)

Answer (score 0):

A **placement group** controls the locality of the **hosts** that are running the virtual machines.

From [Placement groups - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html):

> A cluster placement group is a logical grouping of instances within a single Availability Zone. A cluster placement group can span peered VPCs in the same Region. Instances in the same cluster placement group enjoy a higher per-flow throughput limit for TCP/IP traffic and are placed in the same high-bisection bandwidth segment of the network.

The instances always remain as independent virtual machines. There is no concept of "sharing operating systems" between instances, regardless of whether they are in a placement group.

Instances that run a **container service** (eg Docker) will share operating systems, but that is all within a single Amazon EC2 instance.